# i write a code for calculator in gtk3 c the code is total numbers, in i write 1+1+1+1 the result is 3+1 i want to fix to 4

Tags: c, calculator

i write a code for calculator in gtk3 c the code is total numbers, in i write 1+1+1+1 the result is 3+1 i want to fix to 4
[calcul](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1qmw.png)
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqVFe.png)

in i write sprintf(result,"%d%s",temp,rest); the result for 1+1+1+1 is 3+1 i want to result 4
i check for sprintf(result,"%d",temp); is not correct.

the code of application :

```
#include<gtk/gtk.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<assert.h>
int calculate(int x ,int y ,char op)
{
    if(op == '+')
    {
        return x + y;
    }
    return -1;
}
char *parseMath(const char *s, char *result)
{
    int x;
    int y;
    char op;
    sscanf(s, "%d%c%d", &x,&op,&y);
    int offset = snprintf(NULL,0,"%d%c%d",x,op,y);
    const char *rest = s + offset;
    int temp = calculate(x, y, op);
    printf("%d\n",strlen(result));
    sprintf(result,"%d%s",temp,rest);

    if(rest[0]=='\0')
    {
        return result;
    }else
    {
        return parseMath(result,result);
    }
}
static void on_button_press(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer buffer)
{
    const char *label = gtk_button_get_label(GTK_BUTTON(widget));
    if(*label=='=')
    {
        const char *exp = gtk_entry_buffer_get_text(buffer);
        char *result = malloc(sizeof(int)*8/3+2+strlen(exp));
        char *ans = parseMath(exp,result);
        gtk_entry_buffer_set_text(buffer,ans,-1);
        assert(result!=NULL);
        free(result);
    }else{
    guint len_buff = gtk_entry_buffer_get_length(buffer);
    gtk_entry_buffer_insert_text(buffer, len_buff, label, -1);
    }
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    gtk_init(&argc,&argv);
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *entry;
    GtkWidget *button,*button2,*button3,*button4;
    GtkWidget *grid;
    GtkEntryBuffer *buffer;
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window),"calculator");
    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    grid = gtk_grid_new();
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window),grid);
    buffer = gtk_entry_buffer_new(NULL,-1);
    entry = gtk_entry_new();
    gtk_entry_set_buffer(GTK_ENTRY(entry), GTK_ENTRY_BUFFER(buffer));
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), entry, 0, 0, 4, 1);
    button = gtk_button_new_with_label("0");
    g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(on_button_press), buffer);
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid),button, 0, 1, 1, 1);
    button2 = gtk_button_new_with_label("+");
    g_signal_connect(button2, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(on_button_press), buffer);
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid),button2, 1, 1, 1, 1);
    button3 = gtk_button_new_with_label("1");
    g_signal_connect(button3, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(on_button_press), buffer);
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid),button3, 2, 1, 1, 1);
    button4 = gtk_button_new_with_label("=");
    g_signal_connect(button4, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(on_button_press), buffer);
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid),button4, 3, 1, 1, 1);
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why don't you call `calculate` til the string which don't have any operator(+,-,*/) ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please always narrow down your problem to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your calculation is not related to GTK at all, even less to glade. You could remove all that GTK stuff and just use a fixed string to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you remove all the unrelated code from your example, we get this MCVE:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int calculate(int x ,int y ,char op)
{
    if(op == '+')
    {
        return x + y;
    }
    return -1;
}

char *parseMath(const char *s, char *result)
{
    int x;
    int y;
    char op;
    sscanf(s, "%d%c%d", &x,&op,&y);
    int offset = snprintf(NULL,0,"%d%c%d",x,op,y);
    const char *rest = s + offset;
    int temp = calculate(x, y, op);
    printf("%zu\n",strlen(result));
    sprintf(result,"%d%s",temp,rest);

    if(rest[0]=='\0')
    {
        return result;
    }else
    {
        return parseMath(result,result);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    const char *exp = "1+1+1+1";
    char *result = malloc(sizeof(int)*8/3+2+strlen(exp));

    char *output = parseMath(exp, result);
    printf("output: %s\n", output);
}
```

That's much easier for everyone to read as it does not distract with GTK stuff that is not related to your problem with formatting your text.

You should get compiler warning for this line:

```c
printf("%d\n",strlen(result));
```

Function `strlen` returns `size_t` and the correct type to print such a value is `%zu`, not `%d`.

That line also contains another problem:
When you first call that function, you pass the result of `malloc` which points to uninitialized memory. Accessing such a block of memory causes undefined behaviour.

But these 2 issues do not cause your problem.

When you run your program in a debugger (which you clearly should do!) you will see that the first call to `parseMath` will create the correct content for `sprintf(result,"%d%s",temp,rest);`: `"2+1+1"`. And `rest` will point to `"+1+1"` as expected

But then things go wrong. When you call this function recursively you will notice that `rest` changes from `"+1"` to `""` after you call `sprintf(result,"%d%s",temp,rest);` to create your string.

If you look at the [manpage for 'sprintf'](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) you will find that

> ```
>    C99 and POSIX.1-2001 specify that the results are undefined if a
>   call to sprintf(), snprintf(), vsprintf(), or vsnprintf() would
>   cause copying to take place between objects that overlap (e.g.,
>   if the target string array and one of the supplied input
>   arguments refer to the same buffer).  See NOTES.
> ```

And other than with your first call to `parseMath` you provide the same buffer twice when you call it recursively: `return parseMath(result,result);`

The terminating 0 byte of your calculated result `"3+1"` overwrites the `'+'` of `rest` and you decide you have completed your task.

To fix that problem you need to create a copy of that buffer instead of just pointing into `s`.

Finally I stumbled over that weird expression:

```c
char *result = malloc(sizeof(int)*8/3+2+strlen(exp));
```

Where did you get that formula? You are removing 2 numbers + 1 operator and replace them with 1 number. The result cannot be longer than the initial input. Just use `strlen(exp) + 1` to allocate your memory.

Together with the other fixes we get this corrected version:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int calculate(int x ,int y ,char op)
{
    if(op == '+')
    {
        return x + y;
    }
    return -1;
}

char *parseMath(const char *s, char *result)
{
    int x;
    int y;
    char op;
    sscanf(s, "%d%c%d", &x,&op,&y);
    int offset = snprintf(NULL,0,"%d%c%d",x,op,y);
    char *rest = strdup(s + offset);
    int temp = calculate(x, y, op);
    printf("%zu\n",strlen(result));
    int done = rest[0]=='\0';
    sprintf(result,"%d%s",temp,rest);
    free(rest);

    if(done)
    {
        return result;
    }else
    {
        return parseMath(result,result);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    const char *exp = "1+1+1+1";
    char *result = malloc(strlen(exp) + 1);
    *result = 0;

    char *output = parseMath(exp, result);
    printf("output: %s\n", output);
}
```

Comment: As a sidenote, that whole approach using `snprintf` to determine how many bytes were consumed is rather broken. If you add `01+1+1` you will get a wrong result as leading 0s will not be preserved.

Comment: thank you Gerhardh i replacing  char *result = malloc(sizeof(int)*8/3+2+strlen(exp)); by char *result = malloc(strlen(exp) + 1); is work

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean it solved your problem? Then that is not correct. Using `strdup` (or any other way to make a copy) is key to solving your problem. But that smaller size is sufficient to hold the result. The code I show above is tested.

Comment: Gerhardh it solved my problem

Comment: Definitely not. You allocated more memory than needed. That is just a waste of memory but does not cause any problems unless you run out of memory. Your incorrect usage of overlapping strings caused the issue. Read the manpage I linked, check your buffers in the debugger. Then you will understand that that `malloc` size does not fix anything.

Comment: You should not just grap one random piece of the provided code but also read and understand the answer.