# i write a code for calculator in langage c ,in i write 1+1+1+1 in float i return not result but for 1+1=2 i find result i want to fix

Tags: c, calculator

i write a code for calculator in langage c ,in i write 1+1+1+1 in float i return not result but for 1+1=2 i find result i want to fix.

i use calculate function for a som ,and parsemath for result

the code of application :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

float calculate(float x, float y, char op)
{
    if (op == '+')
    {
        return x + y;
    }
    return -1;
}

char *parseMath(const char *s, char *result)
{
    float x;
    float y;
    char op;
    sscanf(s, "%f%c%f", &x, &op, &y);
    int offset = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%f%c%f", x, op, y);
    const char *rest = s + offset;
    float temp = calculate(x, y, op);
    printf("%zu\n", strlen(result));
    float done = rest[0] == '\0';
    sprintf(result, "%f%s", temp, rest); //%.2f
    if (done)
    {
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        return parseMath(result, result);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    const char *exp = "1+1+1+1";
    char *result = malloc(strlen(exp) + 1);
    *result = 0;

    char *output = parseMath(exp, result);
    printf("output: %s\n", output);
}
```

Comment: The wording of the question is unclear. What is the result you are expecting, for which input and what would you want to fix in it?

Comment: i want return  1+1+1+1 output 4 use function calculate and parsemath

Comment: Even if it may eventually work in your case, the length of string obtained with x,op,y may be different from what was in original string.

Comment: I already told you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70803906/i-write-a-code-for-calculator-in-gtk3-c-the-code-is-total-numbers-in-i-write-1/70805654#70805654) that your usage of overlapping buffers causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @karraz it will not work this very naive way.

Comment: You probably want to use a [shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).

Comment: @Gerhardh - is this question the same (or similar) to the one you linked?

Comment: Aside: `float` is *useless* for even a basic 8-digit calculator. It doesn't have enough precision. Move up to `double` asap.

Comment: For any serious expression parser you probably want to build up a binary expression tree.

Comment: @ryyker It is very similar, close to identical. But I did not look into the new question close enough to tell if the use of `float` is adding more issues on top. Hence I did not suggest it as dupe.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem is :

```
printf ("%f%c%f",x,op,y)
```

for x,op,x = 1,’+’,1 is :

> 1.000000+1.000000

not

> 1+1

You can this line in you code just before snprintf in you code

Comment: Really - try it first yourself

Comment: I made a copy paste from program output wher I added the line. The %f by default as 6 decimals after dot.

Comment: Really? `printf ("%d%c%d",x,op,y)` if anywhere o the list are floats - it is UB

Comment: @0___________ : sorry I put the wrong format in my answer.

Comment: Ptit Xav is correct Is 1.000000+1.000000 not 1+1 i use "%.0f%c%.0f"

Answer (score 0):

The strtof function returns the position after parsing a float.

```
float x = 0, y;
char *next = s;
while(*s) {
    y = strtof(next, &s);
    if (s == next) break;
    op = *s++;
    if (op == 0) break;
    x = calculate(x, y, op);
    next = s;
}
```

Note that this gets more complicated if you want to add precedence.